# AngularJS - importing controllers inside controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have diferents controllers in my webpage, each controller is in a different .php document. Each .php document represents a diferent part of the webpage. (It's similar to spotify).

**player.php:** (Where the user can play some music with an audio player)

```
<html ng-app="decibels-interactive" lang="en">
<body ng-controller="InteractiveController as interactCtrl">
```

**panel_admin.php:** (where the user can modify its data and some data of the webpage)

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="decibels-admin">
<body ng-controller="AdminController as AdminCtrl" ng-init="AdminCtrl.sessionCtrl()">
```

player.php and panel_admin.php have its respective **player.js and panel_admin.js** with its .controllers running correctly.

**player.js:**

```
var decibelsInteractive = angular.module("decibels-interactive", []);
decibelsInteractive.controller('InteractiveController', function ($scope, $log) {
```

**panel_admin.js:**

```
var adminControl = angular.module("decibels-admin", []);
adminControl.controller("AdminController", function($scope){
```

Now, I have the menu bar in menu.php, where I use in **player.php** document, imported with:

```
//player.php

<html ng-app="decibels-interactive" lang="en">
<body ng-controller="InteractiveController as interactCtrl">

<?php include('includes/menu.php'); ?>
//here some html code
</body>
</html>
```

**menu.php:** (menu is a menu bar where the user have some options, and it also have its username and logout option)

```
<div class="navbar-fixed"  ng-controller="InteractiveController as menu2">
  //some html code
</div>
```

**menu.js:**

```
app.controller('menu2', function($scope) {
$scope.content = '';
```

});

The problem that I have is that as you can see, I import the document **menu.php** inside **player.php**. 
I also want to import the **menu.php** inside **panel_admin.php** and be able to use some methods that I have in **menu.js**, so the code that I have in **menu.php** (ng-controller="") is not correct (or I think so). -Because when I use it in panel_admin.php it will be in conflict with ng-controller name.

Someone told me that I should use services, or that I should define menu in separate module and use it as dependency where I want.

I am new with angularJS so now I'm a little lost. I've been searching information about services and dependencies without success.

I hope to solve this problem and being able to continue programming!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm truly confused by your question. What are `player.php` and `player_admin.php`? Are these different "apps"? Please explain your use case (not the behavior you're after). Also, "controller as" just defines the alias for an existing controller (in your case, `menu2` is an alias for `InteractiveController`), so `app.controller('menu2', ...` defines a completely new controller.

Comment: **player.php** is one of the multiple pages that I have in my webpage. This have a player where a user can play songs. **panel_admin.php** is where the user is able to modify some of its data. Maybe I should only use 1 ng-app for the whole webpage? - Now, I want to be able to use the **menu.php** (the menuphp, the file that I import, is a menu bar where the user will have some options, like its username, loggout, etc...) so I need the **menu.php** in diferent pages .php @NewDev

Comment: What is a "page" in your terminology? If it is a different endpoint of your webserver (crudely speaking, a different `index.html`), then each one is a separate and independent Angular app. Also, Angular doesn't care about server-side "includes" - it is bootstraped and runs on a client, with whatever `.js` files you have.

Comment: @NewDev With "page", I meant for example, the webpage starts at **index.php**, then the user loggin and is redirect to **player.php**, if when the user is listening songs in **player.php** and want to modify some sata of the app (delete one of its playlists) it will click one of the menu options and will be redirected to **panel_admin.php**.

Comment: Yeah, so as I said, each web page is a separate Angular app. Angular is used for Single Page Applications (SPAs). So, I'm still unclear on what the problem is. Maybe your question is about how to make your app more modular (i.e. reusable `menu` include), but I don't think there is enough detail to understand the issue. Perhaps someone else would have a better handle on it.